# Is Tristana immune to crowd control whe she starts her rocket jump?

Tags: league-of-legends

I noticed Tristana will jump regardless if you stun, snare, hook or whatever her at the moment she is about to take off. I got knocked in a wall once by Vayne's condemn but still managed to actually jump. I was briefly stunned when i landed but nowhere near the full stun duration.

This happens with other stuns as well, such as taric's dazzle. If you cast Tristana's rocket jump just before you get hit by the stun you will still jump. Unlike Caitlyn which will still shoot her net when stunned but won't actually get pushed away.

I know some ultimates like ezreal's barrage and lux' laser cannot be interrupted but Tristana's jump isn't an ultimate. And Gnars wallop cannot be interrupted either but the tooltip does actually mention this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With both Tristana's Rocket Jump and Ezreal's Arcane Shift, there is a slight delay between when the ability is cast and when the dash/blink starts. In between these moments, crowd control will be applied, but will be canceled/overridden by the movement of the ability. This is particularly potent when dealing with hooks, immobilization, and stuns, and is strangely not documented on either the ability descriptions or the wiki.

While in the middle of the jump, any crowd control which is considered "airborne" (that is, knockups, knockbacks, and pulls) will cancel the jump. Knockups will hold her in place, and knockbacks and pulls will take effect as though she weren't in the jump. Any other crowd control will be applied, but will not affect her ability to move, attack, or use abilities until after the jump.

Comment: Vayne's condemn is a strange case then. You won't be knocked back but you can still get stunned as if you were knocked back.

Comment: I imagine Condemn checks whether you *should* run into a wall from the knockback, and applies the stun regardless.

Comment: @AverageUnknown If that were true, there would be little to no reason to condemn-flash. Condemn appears to knock back a certain range and checks if the enemy is within range of terrain from a particular angle.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I don't think I said anything that contradicts you, but maybe I was unclear. What I meant was that, in our hypothetical, Trist would be knocked back, then the delayed jump would override the CC, but the stun would be applied anyway because (presumably) the system only checks whether the projectile reached its target and whether the path from Vayne through the target was aimed at a wall.

Answer (score 0):

On the lol wiki if you look under abilty details [Tristana's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/tristana) rocket jump:

> Non-Airborne crowd control effects, such as  stuns and Root , will take effect upon landing and will not cancel the jump, with the exception of Veigar's Event Event Horizon.
>
> All Airborne crowd control effects, such as knockups, knockbacks and pulls, will cancel the jump and then complete their effects as normal.

**So you are not immune to CC, but you wont stop moving till you land.**

But blitz pull and vayne's condemn, should have stopped your jump. (might be some bug or something with timing)

Comment: Hm i understand the blitz pull. I know an Ezreal can get hit but still shift away. Vayne's condem is rather fast so maybe that messes things up a bit

Comment: @M'vy The article text says pulls and knockbacks will cancel the jump.

Comment: It's actually pretty known that it's a timing thing to avoid blitz's pull and I imagine Vayne's condemn is pretty similar.  I've seen someone replicate it on purpose 3 times in a row vs a blitz hook.  It's tough but nowhere near impossible.